# How would I construct a decision tree from this data?

Tags: machine-learning

I am working on a exam past paper. I need to use the ID3 algorithm to predict whether a pizza will be found delicious. I have calculated the values for each category as follows:

Toppings = 0.459, Spicy = 0.6, Crust = 0.6666 and Temperature = 0.87399

However I am now stuck in building the decision tree. At the moment I have 'Toppings' as the root node, but I can't find the next split at the second level, does anyone have any ideas how to go about this correctly?

Comment: Have you done any research into how the ID3 algorithm works? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have used the ID3 algorithm to calculate the above four values, I have then created the initial tree with spicy, temperature and crust as leafs. However, i can't split these further as they all give the same values. But I should be able to split one level further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your questions needs more clarity. You need to give us the number of positive and negative samples. What is the meaning of "Calculated values". What are these values? Are these the Information Gain? Tell us more about the kind of data you are dealing with. (*partially labelled? Continuous?*). What do you mean by, "splitting it further"? What are your total number of attributes?

http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/courseware/cse5230/2004/assets/decisiontreesTute.pdf

The above URL has a very good explanation of Decision Trees based on Tom Mitchell's book on Machine Learning.